# Issue Loading PopperJS and Bootstrap via RequireJS, Even After Using Recommended PopperJS Version

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I'm attempting to load jquery, popperjs, and bootstrap (v4-beta) via requirejs and in the console I keep getting:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)
    at bootstrap.js:6
    at bootstrap.js:6
    at bootstrap.js:6
```

Here's my code in main:

```
requirejs.config({

  paths: {
    'jquery': 'lib/jquery',
    'popper': 'lib/popper',
    'bootstrap': 'lib/bootstrap'
  },

  shim: {
    'bootstrap': ['jquery', 'popper']
  }

});

requirejs(['jquery', 'popper', 'bootstrap'], function(jquery, popper, bootstrap) {});
```

This has already been asked a few times regarding issues with loading popper.js and bootstrap with requirejs.  **Yes**, I'm using the umd version referenced [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23381#issuecomment-324257061).

Everything is loading properly into the page:

```
<script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="main" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery" src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="popper" src="js/lib/popper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="bootstrap" src="js/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I'm confused as to why I'm still getting this error and am starting to think it's something with my require config.  Any ideas?

Comment: I use what Bootstrap gives <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> and it's loaded before my </body> tag

Comment: also this goes in the <head> section   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: @mlegg I don't have any issues with either of those methods.  My issue arises when I utilize requirejs to load everything.

Comment: The requirejs build of Bootstrap beta.1 is kind of buggy, it expects Popper.js to be available in the global scope. They should fix this problem in the next release

Comment: The library is `popper.js`, not `popper`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until [Bootstrap PR #22888](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/22888) is released, this is how I've fixed the `Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)` issue...

Similar to what's mentioned in other [blog posts](http://blog.chasepeeler.com/2017/09/12/bootstrap-4-and-requirejs/) the idea is to create your own module that wraps Bootstrap. This module then loads and sets `popper.js` in the prescribed manner before loading `bootstrap`:

```js
requirejs.config({
    "paths" : {
        "jquery"        : "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min",
        "popper"        : "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min",
        "bootstrap"     : "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min"
        "initBootstrap" : "...wotever..."
    },
    "shim" : {
        "bootstrap" : ["jquery"]
    }
});

...

define("initBootstrap", ["popper"], function(popper) {
    // set popper as required by Bootstrap
    window.Popper = popper;
    require(["bootstrap"], function(bootstrap) {
        // do nothing - just let Bootstrap initialise itself
    });
});
```

Now let your code / website have a dependency on `initBootstrap` and not `bootstrap`.

Or as [chasepeeler](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23381#issuecomment-330859809) mentions, if you don't want to create a new module, you can just add a require statement:

```js
require(["popper"], function(popper) {
    window.Popper = popper;
    require(["bootstrap"]);
});
```

*Note this is also posted on the [Bootstrap Popper Issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23381#issuecomment-330850892) on GitHub.*

Comment: The same code above works without errors for me. This looks fine with Bootstrap **4.0.0.-beta**, but when try to use the latest Bootstrap **v4.0.0** (only remove the '-beta') there is an error saying that `popper.js` is not found because it looks for it in the root of the project. When I put on the root It works, but that's not the proper way. Someone had the same issue?

Comment: Yes, @Leo it is true. 4.0.0-beta was the last version of unbundled bootstrap to work with requirejs. For solution, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260089/require-js-load-cdn-bootstrap-and-cdn-popper

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively-
"bootstrap.com/contents": Bundled JS files (bootstrap.bundle.js and minified bootstrap.bundle.min.js) include Popper, but not jQuery.

So I added it to my library. Changed the name ( "bootstrap.bundle.min.js" -> "bootstrap.min" ), created a path for bootstrap and a shim for jquery. Seems to have worked for me.

Comment: just to be clear require bootstrap.bundle.js and not bootstrap.js. Thank you ogginger

Answer (score 0):

This works for me;

```js
require.config({
    
    shim: {
        'bootstrap' : ["jquery"]
      },
      paths: {
        'jquery': '../jsLibrary/jquery',
        'popper': "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min",
        'bootstrap': "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min",
        'tatMusic': '../music/tatMusic'
      }
});

require(["tatMusic","popper"], function(Music,popper){
    window.Popper = popper;
    require(["bootstrap"], function(bootstrap) {
    });
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes